# Anime preview about a young girl standing in a window being pulled upward by illuminated strings

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this preview for what looked like an anime in the 90s or early 00s. I can't remember what film it was shown as a preview in, but I remember a few details:

There was a scene of the preview with a young girl standing in an upstairs window of a house during a "storm" and some thing rope-like, or strings that were illuminated, like a light string, ties around her wrists and pulled her upward.
Another scene looked like a dude was making her marry him.

Comment: Did it look like she was willing as she was being lifted by the light string, or was she being removed against her will?